# Can System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll be used in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, dll, .net-4.0

I have .net 4.0 installed on my computer..But I have VS 2008.

Can  `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll` be used in VS 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not help you.

If this DLL is included with the .NET 4.0 redistributable, then you should have it installed already, and if you don't, you need to [re-download and re-install the redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718) from Microsoft's website. This will allow you to run an application that was written and compiled for .NET 4.0.

If it is *not* included with the .NET 4.0 redistributable, then you will be unable to use it. Visual Studio 2010 is required to create .NET 4.0 applications; you can't use VS 2008 no matter what DLLs you may have.

In general, having people send you a DLL file is an *extremely* bad idea. And remember that software piracy is *also* an extremely bad idea (and illegal!). You need to **purchase** a copy of Visual Studio 2010 if you want to develop .NET 4.0 applications, or use the free Express edition, obtainable [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express).

Comment: I don't see him admitting to any blatant piracy

Answer (score 2):

You need VS 2010 to build .NET 4.0 applications

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use .Net 4.0 assemblies in earlier versions of the runtime.